# How can I search new inserts in my access database?

Tags: java, sql, ms-access

I created an AddressBook GUI application with Insert, Update, Delete, Search, and Print functions. It connects to my access database table which contains four tables(names, addresses, phoneNumbers, and emailAddresses)

So far everything is working except when I try to search new input I just inserted into the table. If I search records I placed directly into access it works.

I THINK I narrowed down the problem but don't know how to fix it. When I insert new records into my table the names table creates a new primary key for that record but the rest of the tables don't, they only create a new foreign key number. Since my search is based on inner joining the id's I'm guessing my problem lies here but I'm not sure.

Here Is my Search Code

```
if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Search")){
    JFrame mini = new JFrame();

    // Gets user input. If user presses Cancel, 'name' will be null
    String first = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(mini,"Enter first name:");
    String last = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(mini, "Enter last name:");

    try{

            resultSet = statement.executeQuery( "SELECT * FROM ((names INNER JOIN addresses 
                    ON names.personID = addresses.addressID)INNER JOIN phoneNumbers
                    ON names.personID = phoneNumbers.phoneID) INNER JOIN emailAddresses 
                    ON names.personID = emailAddresses.emailID 
                    WHERE lastName LIKE '%" + last + "%' AND firstName LIKE '%" + first+"%'");

            resultSet.next();

            jTextField1.setText(resultSet.getString("firstName"));
            jTextField2.setText(resultSet.getString("lastName"));
            jTextField3.setText(resultSet.getString("address1"));
            jTextField4.setText(resultSet.getString("address2"));
            jTextField5.setText(resultSet.getString("city"));
            jTextField6.setText(resultSet.getString("state"));
            jTextField7.setText(resultSet.getString("zipcode"));
            jTextField8.setText(resultSet.getString("phoneNumber"));
            jTextField9.setText(resultSet.getString("emailAddress"));
            jTextField10.setText(resultSet.getString("personID"));
            jTextField10.setEditable(false);

        } catch(SQLException sqlException) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, sqlException.getMessage(), "Error",
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }

}
```

Comment: So, the personId is auto-generated on insert? If so, one way is to retrieve the newly created key at that time and save one or more of those locally.

Comment: Just to make a suggestion if your query didn't return any data use of  `resultSet.getString("firstName")` below the `resultSet.next();` line give you an error `java.sql.SQLException: Illegal operation on empty result set.` instead I suggest `if (resultSet.next()) {
                jTextField1.setText(resultSet.getString("firstName"));
            }`

Comment: Hint: having variables named a1,a2,a3 ... isn't good practice either. At least: put the *meaning* into the name, like tfFirstName ... and so on. Then at least you know what that textfield is supposed to keep. Manual counting is just a bad idea!

Comment: No the personID isn't auto generated. I tried auto generating it in Access but it says it cant because of the relationship to the name table. Also you cannot insert a personID through Insert on my gui if that was what you meant

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @GhostCat

Answer (score 0):

Access uses `*` as the wildcard character, not `%`

Comment: It works as in "returns results"? If you run this query directly in Access? It won't crash but it should be looking for names that actually are `%lastname%` instead of containing `lastname`